# Why EU/US airline checked baggage allowance limited at 32kg?

Tags: usa, weight-and-balance, airlines, eu

For most full services on EU/US airlines, the permitted weight of each of the checked baggage allowance is 32kg. It is similar for the routes operated by non-EU/US airlines, even though their overall checked baggage allowance is more than that. What are the reasons behind that?

Comment: Presumably it's as small as airlines can get away with. With my cynical hat on, this will increase the number of excess baggage surcharges...

Comment: For the specific value, 23 kg is 50 lbs., so it's probably something that started in the US.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, perhaps you could try to clarify it? Most airlines allow you to push the weight up to 32kg/70lbs as an absolute limit (possibly with extra charges). Heavy bags slow operations. 5 seconds extra on 100 bags is 8 minutes extra of work. They also cost expensive fuel: for instance 5kg extra among 150 passengers on an A320 would weight 750kg, in relation to an empty weight of 61,000kg.

Comment: @MikeFoxtrot  Thnak for your comment. It is 32kg not 23 kg. But i know "Heavy bags slow operations", what i ask is why not 31/33kg?

Comment: I guess it's just a simple rounded imperial measurement unit of 70lbs that was chosen in the past, perhaps by some organization, and that has stuck and been accepted. [IATA](https://www.iata.org/whatwedo/ops-infra/baggage/Pages/check-bag.aspx) also follows it.

Comment: @Him Same reason why they'd use 23kg for luggage that doesn't require an extra charge: the real number is 70 lbs, probably originating in the US (or the UK pre-metric). People elsewhere adopted the same number, but they didn't use pounds, so they converted it to kg (where it rounds to 32 kg). Similarly, a football goal is 7.32m wide and 2.44m high -- it started out with different units where the numbers make sense (8 yds by 8 ft), and was then converted to metric. This is often the case when you find odd specification: it's converted from a measurement system where it was a nice round number.

Comment: @cpast You misunderstood my question. I am asking why it is 32kg/70lbs but not 71lbs/69lbs, not why it is using metric system but not imperial units.

Comment: @Him Because 70 lbs. is a nice round number. They did not set it based on detailed analysis; they decided 70 lbs. was about right (for whatever reason), and didn't go more precise than to the nearest ten pounds because there's really not much point.

Comment: It could be to have universal requirements. On jets, this probably isn't an issue, but think of all the hard working regional jets and turboprops.

Comment: So... [exactly what do you need to carry in your luggage that weighs more than 32kg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1CYg0vIygE)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To add to Antzi's answer it is most likely about worker safety. Your question is where do the 50lbs/23kg and 70lbs/32kg numbers come from. The current answer for US based airports would be the recommendations of the Occupational Safety and Health Administration (OSHA). Here [is a link](https://www.osha.gov/dts/osta/otm/otm_vii/otm_vii_1.html#appendix5) to their current lifting standards. There is a neat worksheet down at the bottom for calculating the weight a worker should lift based on the types of movements they have to perform, distances traveled, angles bent. It is a system based on multipliers whose base limit on a normal lift is 51lbs/23.4kg. Then 70lbs/32kg would amount to the multipliers all working out to 1.4 which is again a nice round number.

I would also speculate that at some points these numbers made it into union contracts for ground workers but I have no actual information on that.

What I couldn't find were the OSHA regulations that were in force when IATA first enshrined 23 and 32kg into their rules. It is perhaps a bit disappointing that the current OSHA regulations to not have a "max lift" number but their interest is in reducing injury and a single very heavy lift is apparently less damaging than repetitive above average lifts.

Comment: Bolstering the "worker safety" aspect is the US Postal Service package weight limit (also 70lbs / 35 kilos, and imposed for the safety of mail carriers who have to haul the package around). For their part OSHA doesn't have a specific regulatory limit as far as I'm aware, but if you poke around they start making noise about lifting anything heavier than 50lbs (22.5 kilos).

Comment: (+1) All multipliers in the equation are below 1, though. On the earlier version see https://www.longdom.org/open-access/the-niosh-lifting-equation-for-manual-lifting-and-its-applications-2165-7556-1000159.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Because people have to handle your luggage by hand, which is quite a hard job. 
Heavier luggages would pose a health threat for them, putting even more stress on their back.

I once flew with a heavier (>32kg) luggage on a Seoul-Taipei flight and the ground staff was not pleased at the checking counter...

Comment: Any other reasons?

Comment: I think it is a valid reason.